# du command not counting some subdirectories

Tags: sudo, macos-mojave, du

Calling:

`sudo du -sh /var`

returns:

`0B   /var`

but calling:

`sudo du -sh /var/log`

returns:

`613M /var/log`

Why is `du` not counting subdirectory despite `sudo`?

Also some items gave `Operation not permitted` errors with `sudo` like:

`sudo du -sh /private/var/db/fpsd/dvp`

`du: /private/var/db/fpsd/dvp: Operation not permitted`

My machine is running macOS Mojave 10.14.6. Is there a way to allow `sudo` to access these "hidden" files?

Comment: `du` means diskusage and `/var` is not a disk :) I don't know the answer but can imagine there might exist invisible *mount namespaces* or selinux-like *(MAC) mandatory access control* restrictions. It might also the reason that BSD `du` does not work as expected, try GNU `du` or busybox `du` maybe?

Comment: I will hazard a guess and say that `/var` is a symlink and running `du` against a symlink, always returns zero bytes. Whereas `/var/log` is a real directory.

Comment: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/04/28/sierras-system-integrity-protection-sip-beyond-root

Comment: @Bib you're right! dumb of me to not have noticed this myself. in fact, `/var -> /private/var`, which means my only remaining question is why some items in `/private/var` cannot be operated on by `sudo du`.

Comment: @alecxs i did suspect SIP, but the behavior is not quite the same. SIP protected files can be operated on by `ls -laO` to show its restricted status, but the example file I gave could not even be operated on by `sudo ls -laO`. In contrast, files listed in rootless.conf like `/Applications/iTunes.app` can be listed or read even if they do have restricted status. `du` obviously is a read-only operation which doesn't seem to be related to SIP which is mainly for anti-tampering.

Comment: I don't have macOS but what else could prevent `sudo` *(DAC) discretionary access control* from operating, if not *(MAC) mandatory access control*? Did you disable SIP for testing purposes? [Why Can't I Read /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store under macOS 10.13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315609/why-cant-i-read-private-var-db-configurationprofiles-store-under-macos-10-13)

Answer (score 0):

This might work. It worked for me trying to **ls** the contents of ~/Library/Mail. It was also giving **Operation not permitted**

1. In **System Preferences** select the **Security & Privacy** control panel
2. Unlock the little lock on the bottom of the control panel
3. From the icons on the left of the control panel, select **Full Disk Access**
4. Click on the "**+**" below the list of applications (if any) that already have Full Disk Access over on the right.
5. On the left hand side of the panel, select **Applications** if not already there.
6. You will see a list of folders and your applications. Find and double click the **Utility** folder.
7. You will now see the apps in the Utility folder. Find and double click the **Terminal** application. It will show up on the control panel as having
8. Relock the control panel

I can't guarantee that this will work, buy you have nothing to lose. I would recommend you reverse the process and take **Terminal** out of the list when you are done.